# I want to choose second paragraph

Tags: html, css, selector

```
<div>
<h2>I am another awesome h2</h2>

    <p>Cardigan Tumblr mlkshk, fap tilde 3 wolf moon Portland. Heirloom health goth taxidermy blog lo-fi selfies, post-ironic master cleanse fingerstache normcore. Kickstarter plaid twee, bespoke single-origin coffee sustainable lo-fi vinyl Pinterest pork belly cronut skateboard 3 wolf moon. Normcore single-origin coffee salvia, bespoke Austin swag Godard before they sold out kogi disrupt locavore. Lumbersexual Shoreditch Vice, artisan American Apparel master cleanse yr salvia vegan. Bespoke letterpress heirloom kale chips deep v four loko. Lomo sustainable put a bird on it trust fund post-ironic</p>
    
    <p>I'm the second paragraph inside this div</p>
</div>
```

I want to choose second paragraph but it doesn't work

Comment: This question offers little to no context. Choose it with what? Can you give us the code you have been trying to work with? A little more information would go a long way.

Comment: I think you might mean which selector you use, and you use `p:nth-of-type(2)`. But can you specify that in your question?

Comment: Do you want the content of the second paragraph using js or you want to apply some css to it?

Comment: One more point I forget to mention it. I need to select 2 paragraph inside of 3rd div

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-of-type(n)` to select the second `p` tag.

```css
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>I am another awesome h2</h2>

    <p>Cardigan Tumblr mlkshk, fap tilde 3 wolf moon Portland. Heirloom health goth taxidermy blog lo-fi selfies, post-ironic master cleanse fingerstache normcore. Kickstarter plaid twee, bespoke single-origin coffee sustainable lo-fi vinyl Pinterest pork belly cronut skateboard 3 wolf moon. Normcore single-origin coffee salvia, bespoke Austin swag Godard before they sold out kogi disrupt locavore. Lumbersexual Shoreditch Vice, artisan American Apparel master cleanse yr salvia vegan. Bespoke letterpress heirloom kale chips deep v four loko. Lomo sustainable put a bird on it trust fund post-ironic</p>
    
    <p>I'm the second paragraph inside this div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This command is working. But when I need to choose second paragraph inside the third div it doesn't work

Comment: Show me your html??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you talk about CSS, you can use [:nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) like so:

```
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p:nth-child(3){
color: red;
}
p:nth-child(3) span {
color: green;
}
p:nth-child(3) span:nth-of-type(2){
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>I am another awesome h2</h2>

    <p>Cardigan Tumblr mlkshk, fap tilde 3 wolf moon Portland. Heirloom health goth taxidermy blog lo-fi selfies, post-ironic master cleanse fingerstache normcore. Kickstarter plaid twee, bespoke single-origin coffee sustainable lo-fi vinyl Pinterest pork belly cronut skateboard 3 wolf moon. Normcore single-origin coffee salvia, bespoke Austin swag Godard before they sold out kogi disrupt locavore. Lumbersexual Shoreditch Vice, artisan American Apparel master cleanse yr salvia vegan. Bespoke letterpress heirloom kale chips deep v four loko. Lomo sustainable put a bird on it trust fund post-ironic</p>
    
    <p>I'm the second paragraph inside this div<br>
    <span>Lorem</span><br>
    <span>lorem Ipsum<span>
    </p>
</div>
```

It'll be "nth-child(3)"

Comment: This command is working. But when I need to choose second paragraph inside the third div it doesn't work

Comment: @İbrahimKerimov try using `div:nth-of-type(3) > p:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: Please look at my example. Is that you wanted??